# Kaggle GPU for Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning, model, gpu, training-data, kaggle

I have been using Kaggle GPU for training my deep learning mode. However, after running for continuously for 12 hours the Kaggle kernel stops as a result of which the training stops and I have to restart the training.

Kindly guide me how can I continue training even after 12 hours as I have train for higher number of epochs.
(Sorry for not posting the pics related to kernel stopped after 12 hours).

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

I tried searching over the internet however couldn't get any relevant material.